# Is there an easy way to echo the users city?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the city the user is, I know geolocation isn't completely precise but I would like to get it so I show it as a suggestion to the users.

Is there an easy way to get the users location? With easy I just mean idk copy/paste some code and get the city he is in. I'm using WordPress.

Comment: If you were using Drupal as CMS I would say Yes (the Addressses Module).  But I'm not sure what you're using.

Comment: If there's no Geolocation Wordpress plugin (try googling for one), you'll probably need to invest slightly more work in it than just copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most reliable provider provides that service for free, e.g.

```
  http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19
```

Result would be

> Country: UNITED STATES (US)
>   City: Sugar Grove, IL
>   IP: 12.215.42.19

From PHP

```
  $ip = '12.215.42.19';
  $info = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=$ip");
```

Then with some text processing you can get the city easily.

Comment: How do I get the users IP? Thanks

Comment: That seems like the perfect solution. However it doesn't detect neither my country or my city, is there another provider that does it the same way? I mean that I can add the IP and get the location like that? I found that other sites detected my location but none of htem just returned the info like that

Comment: @Liso22 IP address is stored in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable.

Comment: @Liso22 Some IP are not recognized - there is no perfect system for free, this one belongs to the best team. There are some payed services that would be more accurate.

Comment: Ok, I'll use this one. I have just one more question, I tried echoing that variable just to see if it got my IP but it gave me an error. How am I supposed to call the IP? I manage to do most stuff but I don't really know much about php

Comment: `echo $ip;` should work. As said Nazarly, just do `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` then call `$info = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=$ip");`. You can display the info variable with `echo "$info\n";`